# Background Position Top Right With Specific Img Coords

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown list where the parent node will have an icon to the left of the title. This icon is located in an icons image where there are a dozen other icons. The icon I am trying to use is located at pixel coordinates (0px, 100px) in this image.

I am wondering how would I position part of the image, which is located at (0px, 100px) on the top right corner of my `ul.list > li` element?

`ul.list > li { background: url('images/icons.png') 
 top right 0px 100px no-repeat; } //does not work`

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>Title
    <ul>
      <li>Subs</li>
      </li>Subs</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Fruits
    <ul>
      <li>Apples</li>
      <li>Bananas</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: You edited your question, just remove `top right`

Give your `li` height and width and define `top right` like this

```
ul.list > li { background: url('images/icons.png') 0 100px no-repeat; }
```

Comment: Each of my `li`s has a different width.

Comment: I tried removing the `top right` and just added `0 -100px` (100px didn't work, I needed to add -100px) but it did not work. Note I can't define a width to my `li` as each one has a different width.

Comment: Currently the icon is flush left, where-as I need them placed just to the right of the text.

Comment: @icu222much not getting much without a proper fiddle

Comment: Let me try to mock one up quickly. Sorry.